# Como agrego una clase a una url que usa location en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo varias condicionales de un formulario con checkbox y dependiendo de la combinacion envia a una pagina distinta, una pagina externa, todo funciona pero uso lightbox para mostrar las paginas externas en general, y necesito agregar la clase de lightbox y un rel y no se como, este es el codigo que uso para abrir la pagina nueva cuando se cumple la condicion

```
 if($("#javierm").is(":checked") && $("#homeros").is(":checked") && !$("#caler").is(":checked") && !$("#rositac").is(":checked") && !$("#yolandam").is(":checked") && !$("#reyc").is(":checked")){
        var url = "https://calendly.com/d/xxx/reunion-colectiva-60";
$(location).attr('href',url, '_blank');
        return false;
    }
```

y necesitaria agregarle el rel="noopener" y class="ari-fancybox-iframe" para que lo abra dentro de la ventana lightbox en lugar de salirse de la página.

¿Es posible?
Saludos

Comment: no sé si en alguna parte declaraste una variable `location` pero si ese es el caso, debieras elegir otro nombre. `location` es el objeto que contiene tu ubicación actual. No es un elemento de tipo `a`. Al modificar su atributo `href` estás haciendo, en el fondo `location.href = <URL>` lo cual equivale a redirigir al visitante